# Swapping firstRow and secondRow in a 2D array

Tags: matrix

```
private int [ ] [ ] theMatrix;

//swapRows will snap firstRow and secondRow

public void swapRows (int firstRow, int secondRow)
{

}
```

I need to swap the first and second rows of a matrix using these parameters sos. The text above is what I am given I need to write the code.

Comment: Can you rephrase this? There's not an actual question here. A good question should show what you've tried so far and ask a **specific** question about it. Please also read [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this article](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) on asking for homework help.

Comment: Arr, what programming language are you taking about? Java? if so, edit your question and add the corresponding tag!